# Howcome this ajax http request not working?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to loop thru values and this one under is not working

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:66514/test',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {});
    }
});
```

This one under is working just fine but I'd like the one above to work

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:66514/test', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {});
});
```

So question is, whats wrong with my first ajax call? any help or input highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `sucess` must be `success` :) Typo!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that second one definitely **won't** work based on the url `http://http://`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between these two are:

`$.getJson()` works because returned data is json and you get it in the success callback.

`$.ajax()` on the other hand you have to set the `dataType:'json'` to get the data.

---

Also if you are working with `$.ajax()` then you should use `contentType:"application/json"` when you are trying to send any data to the server.

Answer (score 1):

have you write the right code!!!

because in your code u made a mistake of

```
sucess:
```

instead of

```
success:
```

Comment: sorry, thought it started working but hadn't saved, it doesnt work, voting up tho since u noticed the grammar misstake!